# How to format this PostgreSQL query to be able to run with db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want create the following table. I made it by running the SQL from ActiveRecord using

```
alter table items add column sumup numeric generated always as ( quantity * price + (quantity * price* fpa/100) ) stored;
```

Is that the proper way to do it?

```
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :itemName
      t.string :prom
      t.string :promCode
      t.string :baseCode
      t.string :desc
      t.numeric :fpa
      t.numeric :price
      t.integer :quantity
      t.string :monadaMe
      t.string :familys

      t.timestamps
    end
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(" alter table items add column sumup numeric generated always as ( quantity * price + (quantity * price* fpa/100) ) stored;")
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use proper grammar on SO. Spelling, capitalization and punctuation are important. See "[ask]"

and "[Priority of grammar, spelling and punctuation in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306797/128421)" for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create only the new column:

```
rails generate migration AddSumupToItems sumup:float
```

In your `model`, add:

```
before_save :calculate_sumup

def calculate_sumup
  sumup = ( quantity * price + (quantity * price* fpa/100) )
  self.sumup = sumup
end
```

Comment: i just noticed a bug that when i update the table price the sumup still have the old value..  they way  i do it its work fine even when i update